# PHP dynamic links

Tags: php, html

I am using a php script that takes information from a Google Docs Spreadsheet and displays it in a header. I want to display an image for a currently on air programme, but I'm having to consider folder structure and what will happen once the website goes online.

I tried a fixed link with

```
http://localhost:8080/...
```

and that does the job, but obviously I'll need a dynamic link for a website. Unfortunately, the script reads the link from the page it is on, for instance...

The PHP script is defined on each of the pages with an include:

```
<?php include("widgets/livefeed/onair.php"); ?>
```

**index.html -> Works, because /djs folder is in the main folder**

*Another page inside another folder doesn't work, because it needs ../ before a link so it can go one directory up. Unfortunately, it starts looking for the link from the folder the page is in.*

```
<img src=\"djs/images/onair/desktop/$image\" width=\"210\" height=\"105\" alt=\"{$build[$i][3]}\" title=\"{$build[$i][3]}\" />
```

Comment: You could use absolute paths: `/srv/webapp/widgets/livefeed/onair.php`.

Comment: What if I wanted to use it for both localhost and the website to be able to easily transfer files? Would this work too?

Comment: As long as the paths match, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Define in your index file two variables and use them on each include/require.
Ex:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Usage: `include(ROOT . DS . 'widgets/livefeed/onair.php');`
or

```
<img src=\"<?php echo ROOT . DS . "djs/images/onair/desktop/".$image; ?>\" width=\"210\" height=\"105\" alt=\"{$build[$i][3]}\" title=\"{$build[$i][3]}\" />
```

Comment: To confirm, index.html and put that for every other page I require? Also, what do I put in the dirname bit?